# Как сделать, чтобы for сортировал весь массив?

Tags: python-3.x

Не обращайте внимание на этот код:

```
import random


p = []
n = []
x = random.randint(2,7)
y = x + random.randint(2,5)
a = [[random.randint(-20, 20) for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
b = [[random.randint(-20, 20) for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]

print('Случайная матрица: ')
for i in a:
    for j in i:

        print('|', j, end=' ')

    print('|')

b = zip(*a)
print('Транспонированная матрица: ')
for i in b:
    for j in i:

        print('|', j, end=' ')
    n.append(i[::2])
    print('|')

print(n)

z = 0
for m in n:
    m = sorted(n[z],key=int, reverse=False)
z+=1
print(m)
```

Меня интересует именно эти строки:

```
z = 0
for m in n:
    m = sorted(n[z],key=int, reverse=False)
z+=1
print(m)
```

**Не понимаю, почему цикл не перебирает весь массив**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = [(-8, 4, -5), (14, -12, -13), (-7, -8, -12)]

m = []
z = 0

for i in n:
    m.append(sorted(n[z],key=int, reverse=False))
    z+=1

print(m)
[[-8, -5, 4], [-13, -12, 14], [-12, -8, -7]]
```